# TeXlipse Hyperref generates "Key http://link is undefined" warnings?

Tags: hyperref, warnings

When using the `hyperref` package, I keep getting this warning that says something like:

```
Key ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf is undefined
```

whenever I include an http link.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here is a link to \href{ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf}{The Short
Math Guide}

\end{document}
```

I'm using pdflatex.exe to generate the output, and v6.82h of hyperref.sty.

Comment: Your example document works fine for me. Is that the full error message you get? What version of `hyperref` are you using?

Comment: I am using the MikTeX distribution, with TeXlipse as a front end

Comment: The full warning text is `Key ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf is undefined document.tex line 7 Problem`

Comment: Could you include `\listfiles` in your preamble and look for the `hyperref.sty` version number near the end of your `.log` file?

Comment: It says its v6.82h.  Outputs ("C:\...\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
Package: hyperref 2011/08/19 v6.82h Hypertext links for LaTeX

Comment: Also I am using pdflatex.exe to generate the pdf

Comment: Very strange. I updated to the same version of `hyperref` you're using, but I still can't reproduce the problem. Could you post your complete `.log` file to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and post the link here?

Comment: Your example works fine. But I can get an *error* `! Package keyval Error: ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf undefined. ` if I use angle brackets `\href[..]{...}` instead of correct braces: `\href{..}{...}`. So my guess is you didn't check your example but only believe that it demonstrates your real problem.

Comment: I did!  Oh man.  [Here's a screenie](http://i.imgur.com/s4DQY.png).

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/PmVJawGY

Comment: Please update to kvsetkeys 2011/06/15 v1.14; pdftexcmds 2011/07/28 v0.19; hopatch 2011/06/24 v1.1; refcount 2011/06/22 v3.3; and try again. Could be some old package, but this is just a guess.

Comment: This is a version problem: with an up-to-date TeX Live there is no issue. I'm therefore closing 'too localized'.

Comment: @JosephWright this is a TeXlipse issue (see answer below) so the title should be changed rather than closing the question.

Comment: @gozzilli Specific bugs in software are usually regarded as not something we can keep open, as we can't hope to answer them. So this still stays closed, I'm afraid.

Comment: So sad this is closed, as the problem (I think from TeXlipse) persists. I use Eclipse 3.7.2 with current stable TeXlipse and latest MikTeX 2.9 under Windows. I also got those warnings. They can be **eliminated (workaround) by adding \label{THE_UNDEFINED_LABEL} BEHIND \end{document}** for each problem.

Comment: @BastianEbeling you know if there is another solution, that one isn't working for me and seems like the bug isn´t fixed yet.

Comment: @Dimitri - what exactly is not working? My workaround? Please tell me details.

Comment: @BastianEbeling yes, the workaround wasn't working, but finally it worked, I think it was some problem with some blank space, I´m not sure cause I couldn't replicate the problem. It´s a shame that this problem still occurs on textlipse but at least your workaround solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I guess you are using [TeXLipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/)?

If this is the case your warnings maybe come from a bug in TeXlipse ([this](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2972394&group_id=133306&atid=726818) or [this](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2965444&group_id=133306&atid=726818)).

Comment: And the problem is not solved, yet.

Comment: I also have the problem, which was told by the originator. It seems it has nothing in common with you cited bugs.
As it could be seend in the last (my) comment to the question, there is a workaroung. Could anyone please reopen the question to give me the Chance in answering with the Workaround? Thanks.

Comment: sounds interesting. I am looking forward to your answer!

Comment: @Marcel - you can find it as the last comment to the question: http://bit.ly/TexlipseKeyUndef

Comment: problem not solved, yet